# Authentication issue in laravel login form

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make a login form but it is not working and not giving any error.

my view:

```
<a href="#" data-target="#LoginModal" data-toggle="modal">Login</a>
  <!-- Login Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="LoginModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
        </div>  
        <form class="form" action="{{ url('/login') }}" role="form" method="POST" id="login-nav"> 
            {{ csrf_field() }}  
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" required>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" required>
          </div>
          <div class="help-block text-center"><a target="_blank" href="#">Forget the password </a>
          </div>
          <div class="help-block text-right" id="add_err"></div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Signin</button>
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label> <input type="checkbox">Remember Me? </label>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

my routes

```
Route::post('/login','LoginController@login');
```

my controller

```
public function login(Request $request)
{   
    if(Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($request->only('username','password'),$request->filled('remember'))){
        //Authentication passed...
        return redirect()
            ->intended(route('home'))
            ->with('status','You are Logged in as Admin!');
    }
    return ('failed');

    //Authentication failed...
    return $this->loginFailed();
}
```

when I run my code and submit login form it returns 'failed' which mean if condition not working in my controller so what's the reason behind this

Comment: Welcome to SO ... did you check while register password should be `Hash::make()` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/hashing#hashing-passwords

Comment: Why to check Auth::guard('admin') ? you can check Auth::guard('guest') to check if already logged in or not

Comment: Have you defined **admin** in the guards array of `config/auth.php`

Comment: in my database password is not in hash

Comment: Laravel's EloquentUserProvider validates credentials by checking hash of supplied password with the one in database. So if the passwords in database are not hashed login attempt would fail